# PHP - How to test $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']

Tags: php

I have a function that can be used to redirect the user to different web pages based on the settings of $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].

However, I cannot find a method with Firefox to test this code.

```
Firefox 3.6.8
Tools/Options/Advanced/Fonts
Fonts for // changed this part
Default Character Encoding // changed this part
```

However, the return results from $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] is always as follows:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-us,en;q=0.5
```

Anyone here knows what I should do?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Content -> Languages.
You will see a list of languages. The higher the language is in the list, the higher priority it has.

Comment: I checked all possible options but I missed this one:).

thank you for your helps